# Linux - moving boot, efi, grub to other disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, zfs

I followed this steps:

1. From the desktop, double-click "Install Linux Mint".
2. From "Erase disk and install Linux Mint", click button "Advanced features...".
3. Select option "Erase disk and use ZFS".
4. Check the checkbox for "Encrypt the new Linux Mint installation for security".
5. Continue installing as normal.

[image]

I got this partition table

How can I move unencrypted partitions (boot sector, grub, /boot /efi) to another disk?

Comment: Your 18GB is not really large enough for /? I would just do a new install to drive your really want. Are you booting in BIOS mode using bios_grub partition or UEFI mode using ESP - efi system partition? You do not really need both, although I used to always partition to have both when first starting to use UEFI. UUIDs & GUIDs must be unique, so you cannot easily copy just partitions. Any copy requires deleting old, so you do not have duplicates. And you have to reinstall grub to either update BIOS boot or UEFI boot entries.

Comment: 1) 18GB is fine, its virtual machine for tests 

2) I guess regular old BIOS

3) So will it be enough if I copy /boot /efi and reinstall grub?
Can you provide terminal commands for it? 
I tried few times but as a result I always got blinking _

Comment: I occasionally use cp -a (to preserve ownership) but most often use rsync even for local copies. If using terminal you have to have created partitions in advance and have mounted them. `lsblk -f` to see partitions. Then I use this, but you have to adjust for your partitions. `rsync -aruvlP --delete /mnt/data/Documents /mnt/backup` See `man rsync` for details on parameters.  Trailing slashes matter
When using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the content of the last folder.
When not using "/" at the end of source, rsync will copy the last folder and the content of the folder.